# Mysql search LIKE takes too long

Tags: mysql

Table "businesses" of my database have 100 000 records.
Table "categories" of my database have 900 records.
When i run query

```
    SELECT * FROM businesses b WHERE 
((b.name LIKE '%Fake%' 
AND (b.is_deleted = 0 || ISNULL(b.is_deleted))) 
OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  categories c 
WHERE c.`name` LIKE '%Fake%' 
AND c.is_deleted = 0 AND b.is_deleted = 0 
AND b.`categories_ids` LIKE CONCAT('%|', c.id, '|%'))) 
group by b.id ORDER BY b.`name` ASC LIMIT 0, 20;
```

it only takes 0.06s to return results.
but when i run query

```
SELECT * FROM businesses b WHERE 
((b.name LIKE '%Fake u%' 
AND (b.is_deleted = 0 || ISNULL(b.is_deleted))) 
OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  categories c 
WHERE c.`name` LIKE '%Fake u%' 
AND c.is_deleted = 0 AND b.is_deleted = 0 
AND b.`categories_ids` LIKE CONCAT('%|', c.id, '|%'))) 
group by b.id ORDER BY b.`name` ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

it's just more than one character in the search string, but takes 114s to return results.

why query after take too much time???

Comment: What does the `EXPLAIN` output show about the query execution plans?

Comment: INPUT: string any character here is "Fake" and "Fake u"
OUTPUT: get all business satisfy conditions as above

Comment: When you run **`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`** with each of the two queries, is the execution plan the same, or does the output show a difference?

Comment: The issue here is why 2 query less than only one character, but time the query is too far apart

Comment: The issue here is that its very likely that the two queries are using *different* execution plans. The **`EXPLAIN`** shows the query execution plan. Without the output from `EXPLAIN`, we're only guessing.